# Can a memory leak be a reason of a segmentation fault?

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, segmentation-fault, valgrind

I have a complicated application with lots of third-party libraries, dynamically loaded plugins. And something causes the app to crash (`SIGSEGV`) after main exits. The call stack points to unknown addresses so not only I can't debug, I don't even have an idea where the crash happens.

I tried to run the app with `Valgrind` - it shows leaks (some kilobytes) but I believe that they are false positives and/or I can't do anything about them because they are coming from the third-party.

My question: I believe that memory leaks can't cause a segmentation fault, at least I can't find out the possible scenario. But since I'm not sure I'd like to hear cases when a leak can break the program (assuming it's not a crazy leak when I'm simply out of memory).

Comment: Chances are if you are having memory leaks then you are mismanaging / misusing regions of memory which could result in a segmentation fault.

Comment: Its possible that a leaked object should have cleaned up something when it was destroyed but couldn't since it was leaked and that leads to it breaking during closure.

Comment: @NathanOliver: I think that's commonly called a resource leak. Memory leaks are a subset. But failing to call `operator delete` should never cause a crash. (assuming no silly games with custom `operator new/delete`)

Comment: It is unlikely that the leaks are false positives. You may not be able to do anything about them, in which case you should consider creating a suppression file for them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, memory leaks by themselves would not cause a segmentation fault. However, memory leaks usually indicate sloppy code, and in sloppy code other issues, which would cause a segmentation fault, are likely to be present.

Comment: @S.M. I haven't seen that happen on Linux at least. What I've seen happen is that the kernel kills a process if it cannot map memory. If we're lucky, the kernel chooses to sacrifice the leaky process.

Comment: @S.M. not on any modern system which has a notion of segv. Also, like I said, it is not the leak which is causing the segfault, it is the lack of memory and sloppy code which doesn't perform memory management correctly, so I still stand behind my answer.

Answer (score 0):

No, a segmentation fault in itself is not that much more than trying to access a piece of memory that you are not allowed access to. A memory leak on the other hand is when you allocate some memory and later on 'forget' the location of the piece of memory. The data stored is still there, but it cannot be accessed anymore from that program instance.

Both errors/faults almost always occur because of sloppy coding practices. So it might be possible that the same sloppy coding that causes a memory leak is also responsible for segmentation faults.